# OpenCL Compiler Error C4996

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, opencl

I am new to opencl domian. I have read through some books and try to compile following code

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define __NO_STD_VECTOR
#define PROGRAM_FILE "blank.cl"
#define KERNEL_FUNC "blank"
//#define __MAX_DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE 100

#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

#ifdef Windows
    #include <OpenCL/cl.hpp>
#else
    #include <CL/cl.hpp>
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace cl;

int main() {
    // int n = 10;    
    vector<Platform> platforms;
    vector<Device> devices;

    try {
    } catch (exception e) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me many errors.

most of them are as following

```
Error   14  error C4996: 'cl::vector<char *,10>': was declared deprecated   C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9\include\CL\cl.hpp    1138    1   Matrix_multilpy_C
```

So can any one please help me. I am using visual studio 2013 to code and I have find out my version is openCL 1.2

thanks.

Comment: `using namespace std;` and `using namespace cl`is not a good idea  because you'll get conflicts like `std::vector` and `cl::vector`

Comment: but I have add the #define __NO_STD_VECTOR in the top of the code so I guess that will resolve that confusion, is it? And I have try with out using namespace std; still same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple: The `cl` namespace provides a `vector` class, which you're picking up due to your use of `using namespace cl;`.

Remove that line, `#include <vector>`, remove the `__NO_STD_VECTOR` define and simply use a `std::vector<cl::Device>`, `std::vector<cl::Platform>`. `std::vector` does everything needed; for some reason or another, the OpenCL headers used to ship with a custom vector class, which should not be used any more (I have no idea why it was added in the first place actually.)

You shouldn't be using the `std` namespace either. Notice that once you use both `cl` and the `std` namespace, your code will fail as there will be suddenly two vector classes colliding. So just say no!

Comment: But I have notice that to get maximum portability it is better to use vector class define in the cl.hpp header. Which means shouldn't I have to use cl::vector instead of std::vector.

Comment: Nope, if you use C++, you can use std::vector. Where do you have that from that you should use the cl::vector?

Comment: I have read it from the book 'OpenCL in Action' 8th chapter, section 8.1.1 specifically it says for the platform STL unavailable, the creator of the c++ wrapper coded their own replacement, cl::vector and cl::string, I have look the cl.hpp and it contains these classes.

Comment: If you have a C++ platform without a working STL vector, you shouldn't bother with the C++ bindings anyway.